# Installing migx on modx 2.3.1

Tags: modx-revolution, migx

I am pretty new to modx and trying to install migx. I have been trying for some time now today to follow action two of setup: Set up the MIGX Configurator Custom Manager Page (CMP) and Package Manager.

My problem is that the step by step instructions do not correspond to the latest version of modx, 2.3.1 (I am pretty certain it has installed properly, but may be wrong). It asks for systems > actions > migx from the modx dashboard, but the new version of modx does not have the systems menu, only content, media, extras and manage. Does anybody know therefore how I can complete step two of setup?

link to setup instructions [here](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/migx)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try 2.2.15. There are a lot of changes at manager at 2.3. That's the reason.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice. How would I go about re-installing an older version on my server? At the moment I am developing in a sub-folder, would I have to simply remove the sub folder, unzip modx to another sub-folder and re-install?

Comment: You can just install 2.2 to a new subfolder. If you wish you can remove 2.3. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to skip the whole systems > action part in 2.3. After installing migx you should see it in the Extras top menu, and you can skip directly to step #16 in http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/migx#MIGX-Step1%3AInstallMIGX.

If you installed before upgrading to 2.3 you should only need to reinstall through "extras > installer"

Comment: Thank you, most helpful.